# Is there a way to take a method that creates UI elements and make it cancelable?

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7, grid, rendering

I have a method that gets called when entering a chart page in my WP7 app. It generates a List of objects and populates a ListBox. The content of each ListBoxItem is a Grid with 10 columns of data. The List gets generated incredibly quickly, even with 1000-2000 items. But as soon as the method starts building Grids and adding them to the ListBox it gets relatively much slower. Now, by this I mean it only ties up the the device for half as long as a comparable app on my 2nd gen. iPod Touch. So performance is great - as long as the user wants the data chart.

If the user hits the Start button the app exits so that's not a problem. My concern is when the user backs out to the previous page. The app just waits until the method has run. I notice similar behavior in more mainstream apps like the Kindle app. But I don't have that kind of clout with MarketPlace store! I do have a progress bar that keeps running so the behavior is the same.

Out of concern for being rejected by MarketPlace I tried putting the method into a BackgroundWorker process but that fails because it's in creating the UI elements that is where the bottleneck is and that is running on the UI thread so I get access errors. Is there a way to take a method that creates UI elements, such as a Grid, and make it cancelable?

Comment: Check out my comment in the accepted answer regarding Peter Torr's LazyListBox implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you creating the UI elements within each `ListBoxItem` manually in code? If so, you will find increased performance by using databinding instead because the `ListBox` uses the `VirtualizingStackPanel` as the items container, so it will only actually create UI elements for enough elements to be seen and to scroll to immediately. Other elements are created when the user starts to scroll. The Silverlight for Windows Phone Performance Team have a great post on [ListBox Performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2010/10/06/silverlight-for-windows-phone-7-listbox-scroll-performance.aspx).

If the dataset is particularly large you may find further peerformance improvements by using data virtualization as well (or instead) as Peter Torr explains in his [Virtualizing Data in Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/16/virtualizing-data-in-windows-phone-7-silverlight-applications.aspx) post.

Comment: @ Derek - While doing more research after posting this I had learned this and checked out that post and the code. I'm going to try to make use of it or something similar to chunk the data. Interestingly, I've found that while databinding the UI became a little more responsive. However, scrolling performance with large numbers of rows was really bad. In "normal" usage the user will be happier with better scrolling. It's only the back button issue that I'm really worried about. As mentioned in my OP, the basic performance is way better than the comparable iOS app (altho on old, 2nd gen Touch).

Comment: @ Derek - Regarding Torr's post, I would appreciate it if anyone had an example of using this with some "real" data, e.g. along the lines of what's in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx. I'm finding it difficult to decipher what's IList code and what is being used as sample data.

Comment: I'm in the process of doing this myself and will post an example when I have it all cleaned up.

Comment: So far, testing is positive. There is a small UX penalty when scrolling with smaller result sets vs. my old way of doing it. But with larger results sets, the penalty stays small while before a large result set, e.g. 2000 rows, would take 30 seconds to load and would freeze the backbutton that long. With this new approach, the backbutton is still frozen until the first set of results is painted but it's less than 2 seconds - regardless of the result set size. As mentioned, an example is coming.

Comment: There may be better solutions ultimately, but this has improved greatly on what I had. So far, in testing, max time to create the largest number of list items I'll need is 2 seconds. It's never less, but what's important is it is never more. http://stonetip.com/VirtualizingDataTest.zip is an example I created from Torr's example using some test data and also allows testing the back button.

Comment: While my example - based of Torr's example - is serviceable and an improvement, check out Torr's LazyListBox example @ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/10/12/procrastination-ftw-lazylistbox-should-improve-your-scrolling-performance-and-responsiveness.aspx. It is more complicated, but has everything I'd want in a listbox, including tombstoning right back to where you were in the list and almost instantaneous responsiveness to navigating to or away from the page.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the BackgroundWorker. When you need to update the UI use the following code...

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   textBlock.Text = "some text";
   etc
   etc
}
```

Comment: Yes, and in between adding items, check to see if it has been cancelled.